# DatePicker event "SelectedDateChanged" works not only when date changed

Tags: c#, xaml, silverlight

this is my DatePicker:

```
<sdk:DatePicker Loaded="ToDatePicker_Loaded" SelectedDateChanged="ToDatePicker_SelectedDateChanged"/>
```

It is really reaches the event "SelectedDateChanged" when the date is changes.
The problem is that this event reaches also when page is loaded- something that I don't want to be happen.

How do I fix this problem?

Comment: Trying to get a better understanding or your requirement. what are you trying to do on selection changed

Comment: I am trying to save the date selection. What could be the solution here, that this event will heppen only when the selection is changes and not when the page is loaded?

Comment: Are you using MVVM pattern or are directly interacting with the View/Page. I ask because i want to know if to tailor my answer on the view model or on the VIew itself

Comment: On window loading also the date is changing ,ie,the display date is setting to the Current Date or specified date.